# Importing custom objects

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, data-import-wizard

I have a problem importing and creating more than one custom object at a time using the data wizard. I have created a csv-file with headers that map correctly and imports fine when there is only one line, but fails every line when i try with multiple.

I've also tried the dataloader, but this just gives me the error "id value of incorrect type"

Any suggestions on what might cause these problems?

The CSV-file contains 3 rows, two with strings and one with a number. All values are in quotation marks and i use a comma for delimiter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is setup wrong. You don't need quotes around everything. For example please see a CSV of an import to my custom object 'Dan Object'
[image]

The Name is the standard name field required for new records
Number is a number 
Text is a text or string field

Take the CSV in data loader map the columns to the fields and it should work. If you're doing an update you need the record Id. like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dan,

The structure is as follows:
I have an object "Agreement" with a master-detail relation to another custom object "Invoice". Every month we get a list of invoices for all the agreements, which i need to import as instances of an invoice object for each specific agreement. I match the invoice to the agreement through the name of the agreement.

I don't have a way of extracting all the object ID's of the agreements and matching them with their particular invoice.

I have set up the csv file and the wizard matches the fields correctly. But whenever i try to import, it fails.

Comment: Do you have a column in your file called Agreement that is the record Id of the master record? Because it's a detail the parent Id must be there in the file, and it has to be the correct id, if you don't have the right id you can get that error.